# LINQ Joining 2 tables

Tags: linq, join, entity

I have two tables in the database one contains a list of all possible grocery values. For Example

```
Milk
Cheese
Bread
Meat
```

the second table contains Items from Grocery that are selected. For Example:

```
Milk
Cheese
```

I want a result that has all possible grocery items with Milk and Cheese selected.

Any ideas?

Here are the tables.

```
The GroceryList Table:
ID INT PK
Description Varchar(50)

The ShoppingList Table:
ID INT PK
GroceryListID int FK to GroceryList.ID
```

So the resulting Entity would be all items from GroceryList and if they exist in ShoppingList then selected is marked as true:
ShoppingList.ID
Grocerylists.Description
Selected

Comment: Please post your tables (columns)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear... what do you mean by "I want a result that has all possible grocery items with Milk and Cheese selected."? Can you show us some sample output? Do you just want a list of all the possible groceries with an attribute saying whether or not the item is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on understanding you can do something like this

```
//first get the list of product which satisfy your condition

    var ids = (from p ShoppingList 
              select p.GroceryListID ).ToList();

//second filter the Grocery products by using contains

    var myProducts = from p in GroceryList 
                     where ids.Contains(p.ID)
                     Select p;
```

or

if you want to get info about join than this image would help you

**Inner Join**
[image]

**Outer Join** 
[image]

Try to understand and which may help you to resolve your query

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Still sounds like you want to do a left join.  In your case:

```
var LINQResult = from g in Datacontext.GroceryList
                 from s in DataContext.ShoppingList
                     .Where(c=>c.ID == g.ID)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new {
                    g.ID,
                    g.Description,
                    s.ID   // Will be null if not selected.
                  };
```

For more examples:

[Left Join on multiple tables in Linq to SQL](http://amirrajan.net/Blog/left-join-on-multiple-tables-in-linq-to-sql)